# Save several large Matrix from Rcpp to R environment

Tags: matrix, rcpp, armadillo, r-bigmemory

I used Rcpp (especially Rcpp Armadillo) to perform a method that returns as result several large matrix, for example of size 10000*10000. How can I save these matrix to use them in R environment. Assume that my code in Rcpp looks like:

```
  list Output (20000);
  for( int i(0);i<20000;++1 ){
    ...
    ...
    // Suppose that the previous lines allow me to compute a matrix Gi  of size 10000*10000
    Output(i)=Gi;
  }
  return Output;
```

The way I programmed is very costly and need enough memory. But I need the 20000 matrix to compute an estimator in R environment. How can I save the matrix ? I do not know if bigmatrix package can help me.

Best,

Comment: i) We spell it Rcpp.  ii) 10000 * 10000 * 8 bytes = 800 mb.  Large but not insurmountable.  What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Dirk and thank you for your reply. In fact, I want to use the matrix to build a function that will be maximised numerically. So I tried to put the code that computes Gi matrix inside the function I want to maximise.  But It follows that 20000 Gi will be computed for each iteration of the maximum searching.  This way uses least memory but the computed will never find the maximum. It is too long.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, at each iteration, you compute a 10000 * 10000 matrix and there are 20000 iterations so that you compute an array of 20000 * 10000 * 10000 elements? If it is the case, it means that you want to store 15 TB of data, so you'll need to change your algorithm. Can't you use only summaries of each Gi?

Comment: Hi @F.Prive Thank you for your reply. I post the problem on the mathematics forum. You can get it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626115/maximise-simulated-likelihood)
Thank you so much

Comment: Seems like each element of the sum is independent from the others, so you don't have to compute all Gi at once, but only one at a time. Am I correct?

Comment: I am not sure. In fact G1,G2,... are in some way likely realisations of G. So as I do not know G, I take the mean of the likelihood over Gs.  But I need the parameters that maximise this mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I noticed that I will need 15TB to save the matrices. That is impossible. What I finally did is to save only some features of the matrices, as eigenvalues for example and others. See more details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626115/maximise-simulated-likelihood)